# How to improve a MySQL join query speed?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

Table Name : account

| AccountId | RegDate | Name | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20211101 | Rosa | 1234 |
| B | 20211102 | Daisy | 2345 |
| C | 20211103 | Holly | 3456 |

Table Name : account_history

| AccountId | LoginTime | Os | browser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 202111011303 | mac | safari |
| B | 202111011406 | window | chrome |
| C | 202111012507 | android | chrome |
| A | 202111051903 | mac | safari |
| B | 202111051806 | window | chrome |
| C | 202111052707 | android | chrome |
| A | 202111061603 | mac | safari |
| B | 202111061406 | window | chrome |
| C | 202111072007 | android | chrome |
| A | 202111087303 | mac | safari |
| B | 202111088406 | window | chrome |
| C | 202111089507 | android | chrome |

The result I want.

| AccountId | RegDate | LatestLoginTime | os |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20211101 | 2021202111087303101 | 202111087303 |
| B | 20211102 | 202111088406 | 202111088406 |
| C | 20211103 | 202111089507 | android |

I used

```
SELECT a.AccountId,a.RegDate,b.LatestLoginTime,b.Os 
FROM account a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(LoginTime) as LatestLoginTime,AccountId,Os
           FROM accounthistory GROUP BY AccountId) b
ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
```

But this query is too slow. How can I get the data I want quickly?

Comment: Try running the query with the keyword `EXPLAIN` before, so the db explains how the query is performed and could help in finding a way to optimise it. You can read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: Add `show create table` statement to show table indexes

Comment: There are about 6 different solutions listed for this problem in the following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column You can play around with those solutions as well.

Comment: You can try create another table with selection data. Your table `account_history` it's source logs, if you use for specific grids need create  `account_last_activity` where same columns from table `account_history`.

Comment: it's like be `INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT h.AccountId,
          a.RegDate,
          MAX(h.LoginTime) AS LatestLoginTime,
          h.Os
     FROM Account AS a
LEFT JOIN AccountHistory AS h USING (AccountId)
 GROUP BY h.AccountId, a.RegDate, h.Os
```

With indexes on AccountId in both tables, and LoginTime in AccountHistory.

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06b894/7)

Answer (score 0):

These two indexes may help:

```
account:  INDEX(AccountId,  RegDate)
accounthistory:  INDEX(AccountId,  LatestLoginTime, OS)
```

But there are issues:

- Is `Os` dependent on `AccountId`?  (Cf: only_full_group_by)
- Why `LEFT`?

Depending on your answers, there may be a much better way to formulate the query.

Can one account have two different OS values?

Consider the following:

```
SELECT  a.AccountId,
        b.OS,
        a.RegDate,
        b.LatestLoginTime
    FROM (
        SELECT  MAX(LoginTime) as LatestLoginTime,
                AccountId, OS
            FROM  accounthistory
            GROUP BY  AccountId, OS
         ) AS b  
    JOIN account a  ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
```

If you want just one row per Account, and the OS for that last login, then it is a much more complex query -- Search for "groupwise-maximum".